# Inverting all values in matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

Lets say I have a matrix:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
    2 & 4 \\
    3 & 7 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

And my maximum range value is $10$, how would I go about creating another matrix that inverts those values? So that the matrix would end up looking like:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
    8 & 6 \\
    7 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
In algebraic form?

Comment: What is the maximum range value?

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum range value"? Which "values" are you talking about inverting?

Comment: I've edited your question to use $\LaTeX$.  Please make sure it still represents your original intent.  For help with formatting in the future, please see [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, it **looks** like you're asking the following:

> Given $m>0$, is there some way to transform $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right]\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{cc}m-a & m-b\\m-c & m-d\end{array}\right]$$ for all $a,b,c,d$ between $0$ and $m$ (inclusive)?

The answer to that question is: "Yes, but it isn't necessarily very interesting." Let $J$ be the $2\times 2$ matrix of $1$s. Then for any $m>0$ and any $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ with entries between $0$ and $m$ (inclusive), the matrix $m\cdot J-A$ does the trick (where $m\cdot J$ indicates scalar multiplication by $m$).

If that's *not* what you were trying to ask, then please clarify. It might help if you told us what led you to ask this question, too.

Comment: It may not be interesting mathematically, but it can do some pretty interesting stuff to a black-and-white photograph... `:)`

Comment: @anorton: Fair point...at least, once generalized to bigger matrices. I've yet to see an interesting $4$-pixel photo. ;-)

Comment: But I'm sure that a 4-pixel photo could garner millions at a modern art museum! `:P`  Seriously, that is a fair point as well...  I wasn't thinking about the size of the matrix at all.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the individual entries in the matrix, and see what relationship you can find between those entries, and the "maximum range value".

From your example, in the $(1,1)$ cell in the first matrix, you have the entry $2$.  In the second matrix, you have the entry $8$. Your maximum value is $10$.  Can you see some relationship between the numbers $2$, $8$, and $10$?  Does this relationship hold for the other values? (for example, $3$, $7$, and $10$)

Leave a comment if you need more guidance.  (I'm experimenting with my answering style from just giving an answer to trying a more Socratic method... so I'm looking for feedback.)

Comment: so they would both sum to 10...

does that mean if i had a matrix full of 10's and then subtracted the original matrix from that i would get the inverse :D.. I think thats what i was looking for!

Comment: @TaylorDale yep, that's the idea! Just a side-note: if you're writing up anything about this, you may want to be careful with the term "inverse"--it has a [different meaning](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html) for matrices than you may think. `:)`